# Meteor cordova app not doing hot code pushes

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I built an app on Meteor, and deployed it to a Digitalocean server using `mupx`. On my local machine (where the android SDK is installed), I built the app for android with the following command:

```
meteor build --server=http://SERVER.IP /output/directory
```

I then signed the app and put it on my phone, and it runs fine, and is connected to the database. The problem is that, when I change code on the server, it doesn't automatically get pushed to the app. The only way I've been able to update the app is to build a new .apk and put it on my phone.

Some background info:

I don't have the android platform on the server, only on my local machine, and the hot code push works in the browser when I go to the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems I answered my own question in the question. You really do need to have android on the server, as well as the SDK. Just look up instruction to install the android sdk on a server (no gui). Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

From 1.3-beta.12, added a --server-only option to meteor build that doesn't require the mobile SDKs to be installed on the build machine, but that will still build web.cordova whenios or android platforms have been added to the project.

Reference: [meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cordova-app-android-not-reloading-after-hot-code-push-with-deployed-app/16336/13)